# Purpose of using a saturable logistic like term

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, mathematical-biology

I would like to know what is the purpose of using the term $P\over (k+P)$ in the following.  I found it when reading the article found [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8920248) but it was commonly used in few other related articles .

[image]

Is this similar to a logistic function?

What is the advantage of using this instead of a logistic function?
If this function can saturate, which of the terms does it?

I would be grateful if someone can clarify these.

Answer (score 1):

You are right! the $sX\frac{P}{k+P}$ term is precisely the one that saturates. As $P\to \infty$, this terms goes to $sX$, and so $\frac{dX}{dt}$ remains bounded.

Another way to look at it, is to solve for $X(P)$, yielding

$$\frac{dX}{dP}=\frac{a+sX\left(\frac{P}{k+P}\right)-dX}{rP-hPX} \, .$$

For a given $X(0)$, As $P\to \infty$, you get that $\frac{dX}{dP} \sim O(\frac{1}{P})$ and so the growth in $P$ hardly effects the marginal growth in $X$.